# How to perform UPDATE and DELETE operation in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to perform UPDATE and DELETE operation in Django rest framework, I did GET and POST operation. Please help me to do UPDATE and DELETE operation.

views.py

```
class SettingprofileViews(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Setting_profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SettingprofileSerializer
```

models.py

```
class Setting_profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class SettingprofileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Setting_profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('api/settingprofile', views.SettingprofileViews)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: It may be helpful https://learnbatta.com/blog/viewsets-in-django-rest-framework-83/

Comment: use http PUT requests for updates and http DELETE requests for delete

Comment: @DovRine Where i want to use, please tell me in detail i'm new to django

Comment: I'm on a phone so I can't type too much

Comment: add a url to your view. call that url with http GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE requests as appropriate. l

Comment: Read the docs for ModelViewSet, too.

Comment: I'll check back in a few hours with better instructions if necessary. Good luck.

Comment: Also, it may be easier for you to start with APIView instead of ModelViewSet. It will be much easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: I'm trying but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ModelViewSet already implements actions for PUT and DELETE HTTP methods.

See: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

It means that if you perform HTTP requests:

**DELETE /api/settingprofile/1**

The *restframework* will call *destroy(request, pk=1)* function in order to remove row with id=1 from Setting_profile table.

**PUT /api/settingprofile/2**

The *restframework* will call *update(request, pk=2)* function and inspect *request* parameter, so the row with id=2 in *Setting_profile* table will be changed accordingly to a new data.